# Add multiple activities in one onCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: java, android

i need to put more activities in one onCreateOptionsMenu. 
I have read on documentation which it uses MenuInflater and i dont know how to connect to the menu option.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
    MenuItem new_game = menu.add("Nuova Partita");
    MenuItem help = menu.add("Intelligenza Artificiale");
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.new_game:
            setBoard();
            return true;
        case R.id.help:
            return true;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you want the UI to look like? Please show a mock screen. What do you want to happen when the user taps on each menu item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need add menu items if you already declared them in game_menu. Try something like this but change name with your activities

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
  return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch(item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id.new_game :
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityNewGame.class);
    this.startActivity(intent);
    break;
  case R.id.help:
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityHelp.class);
    this.startActivity(intent);
    break;
  default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

return true;
}
```